# what's the difference between kettle and spark

Tags: apache-spark, etl, kettle

I am fresh about ETL. We are now using kettle to extract message from message queues,and it seems to be streaming or real-time. I wonder if there's any sensible reason to replace kettle with spark or storm or flink? On the other words What's the difference between the group of kettle and powercenter and the group of spark and flink on the perspective of ability to resolve business problems? Any tips will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer? To count the words in a text file:

- with Spark, flink,.. it is code [image]
- with Kettle, Informatica,.. it is visual.[image]